# ViewPager inside Fragment android

Tags: android, android-fragments, android-viewpager

I am using `Fragment` for Slider menu in Android. Source : [Android Slider Menu](http://www.androidhive.info/2013/11/android-sliding-menu-using-navigation-drawer/)

Now, I want to add ViewPager inside first Fragment which is Home. So I found some tutorials for it. But all are using `FragmentActivity` so I am not able to call it inside Fragment.
Please help me regarding this.

Comment: @Fllo, I have checked it. but I am not able to solve my problem.

Comment: @Fllo, yes sir. I have tried so much but still not able to solve problem.

Comment: @Fllo, I had removed all modification code. Have you any tutorial which uses Slider menu using ViewPager ?

Comment: No tutorial, I did not find it yet. I'll try with your last post.

Comment: yup, I also dint find anyone.

Comment: Indeed, it's not really easy to build your feature. As I understand, you have a `Parent Viewpager without Tabs` which should contains `an Inner Viewpager with Tabs`, right? Unfortunately I can't get it, I think this is hard to achieve. However, a solution might be to create a `TabHost` inside your first fragment: you will have Tabs but without viewpager. Or use Viewpager into Viewpager without Tabs.. Good luck.

Comment: @Fllo, I want same as it is in Play Store. Go in Side menu, then my apps -> There you will see 2 tabs. I want same as it is.

Answer (score 0):

I think this should help you out.The key is to use Nested Fragment calls instead of a calling an Activity that uses the FragmentActivity.Find more about Nested Fragment calls [here](http://developer.android.com/about/versions/android-4.2.html#NestedFragments) Please check out this question and see how this is implemented.
[Android: Viewpager inside a fragment of Navigation Drawer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22968306/android-viewpager-inside-a-fragment-of-navigation-drawer?rq=1)